# How to execute jquery with robot framework?

Tags: javascript, jquery, robotframework

When I execute the login test there is a new pop up window without any button to close.
So in chrome devtools I am able to to close with the following command:

```
$(".notouch").remove()
```

and it works.
Now how can i execute this line with robot framework?
I tried this:

```
Execute JavaScript    document.getElementByClass("//[@class='notouch']").remove()
```

Then I received this message:

> FAIL : WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Runtime.evaluate
> threw exception: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list   (Session
> info: chrome=68.0.3440.106)

Comment: I can not replicate this error on Google. The received error is that the function doesn't exist, but then the javascript is already exectured and this error is not that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the page has jquery loaded, it should work to pass the exact same code to `Execute Javascript` that you use in the developer console:

```
execute javascript  $('.notouch').remove()
```

Given this html file in /tmp/example.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    blah blah blah

    <div id="notouch" class="notouch">This is the "notouch" div</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The following robot test passes without error:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Selenium2Library

Suite teardown  close all browsers
Suite Setup     open browser  about:blank  chrome

*** Test Cases ***
Example
    go to   file:///tmp/example.html
    page should contain  This is the "notouch" div
    execute javascript  $('.notouch').remove()
    page should not contain  This is the "notouch" div
```

Answer (score -1):

Correct me if I am wrong, but you are using xpath notation inside `getElementByClass` function. Try this:

```
Execute JavaScript    document.getElementsByClassName('notouch')[0].remove();
```

Comment: thank toy JaPyR, it throws error: FAIL : WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined
  (Session info: chrome=68.0.3440.106)

Comment: Are you sure that the element is present at the moment JavaScript is executed?

Comment: yes i wait until the overlay is visible then i execute the javascript.

Comment: i removed the semi-colon at the end and then i have this error: WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: document.getElementByClass is not a function